# Which Faux Wood Flooring Is Best For Wheelchairs & Incontinent Patients?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

I am replacing the carpeting and contractor-grade flooring in my home. Because of heaving to the ground, the slab has some superficial cracking and the tile has split in my entry. I am unsure if the strips of laminate would be a good choice given I have an elderly parent whose weight is >335lbs and we have incontinent episodes that are cleaned up quickly when I find them, but may occur when I am not aware and sit on the floor for some time.

I noticed at the nursing home where they also had installed the laminate strip flooring that it was marred with wheelchair tracks and had drifted apart in some areas leading me to ask if there is a wide linoleum that would be better? Or was this a case of a bad install?

Comment: Vinyl plank flooring looks good lasts long and glued down resists wheelchair traffic

Comment: + 1 for vinyl plank, but get a quality brand, you don't want a *crappy product* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tile. They make some now that looks like wood flooring
https://www.homedepot.com/b/Flooring-Tile/Wood/N-5yc1vZar0yZ1z0jipd

Comment: You should fix the ground heaving first. It is probably a tree root. As it grows so will any cracks. It will destroy anything you install over it. It could be a drainage issue to. They can inject concrete to fix that. Bottom line until the slab is stable everything will crack or bow.